# how to hide local variables

Tags: c++, coding-style

In my code, sometimes there's a long function, to avoid messed up the local variables, i would use a pair of braces to embrace the details so the local variables will not be visible to the rest of the code, e.g.:

```
bool pricing_deals()
{
  //prepare deal type lookup table
  vector<DealType> deal_types; // deal type lookup table
  {
    vector<DealType> deal_types_TRF; 
    vector<DealType> deal_types_DCI; 
    ...
    // code that prepare deal_types by merging deal_types_TRF and deal_types_DCI etc
  }
  // from now on deal_types_TRF and deal_types_DCI are invisible

  //prepare ccy pair lookup table
  vector<CcyPair> ccy_pairs; // ccy pair lookup table
  {
    // code that prepare ccy_pairs;
  }
  // from now on local variables preparing ccy_pairs are invisible

  // real computation starts
  ...
}
```

I wonder if this is a good practice, or there are other ways of doing so?

p.s. I prefer not to break it into smaller functions in this case, as the sub-logic is not likely to be reused by others, and refactoring will cause a lot of parameters to be passed over, which would increase the complexity.

Comment: cross posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44349932/1896169

Comment: Please, [don't cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/2988).

Comment: See also [How do I ask a “Best Practices” question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8222/1352) and [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/2988).

Comment: @JörgWMittag when I posted in  https://stackoverflow.com/q/44349932/1896169 , it got downvoted and ppl commented (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44349932/how-to-hide-local-variables#comment75702263_44349932 ) i shall post here. After I posted here, ppl comment this is cross posting...

Comment: Your question is off-topic here for the exact same reasons that it is off-topic on [so]. Plus, one additional reason: [softwareengineering.se] is about the SDLC *except the actual coding part*. That belongs on [so].

Comment: @JörgWMittag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style it says "DO NOT USE! This tag refers to an entirely opinionated subject and is therefore no longer on-topic. For questions on coding style, please go to http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com Refactoring, braces, indentation, Hungarian notation, and other stylistic issues relating to code." now you are telling me otherwise. Honestly, i'm lost.

Comment: @athos You're not lost. While we won't help you solve coding problems, we have no problem handling style questions so long as they don't belong in the bike shed. See: [are questions about good coding style on topic](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7790/are-questions-about-good-coding-style-on-topic)

Comment: Hi athos, when you notice you asked a question on the wrong SE site, you can always flag your own question for migration and ask a moderator for help. However, in this case your question could have been closed on stackoverflow also for beeing a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249009/do-you-use-curly-braces-for-additional-scoping), and note this older question was also closed, so I do not see your question has a big chance of surviving, neither here nor on SO.

Comment: ... however, FWIW, IMHO such local scopes are a code smell showing your functions are doing too much. If you have problems to refactor it to smaller functions because of the number of "parameters to be passed over", that is an ever stronger smell for the same reason. I recommend you post a "near real-world" example on "codereview.stackexchange" and ask the community there for refactoring help. Getting a copy of Bob Martin's "Clean Code" book might be also a good idea to clean up the misconception the primary purpose of functions is reuse.

Comment: @DocBrown thx for the suggestion. Yes I shall think about it more clearly in my mind

Answer (score 6):

What's needed here is abstraction.

The single most limiting thing in this situation isn't whether this can be a reusable function or help a unit test. It's whether or not you can give it a good name.

Single use private helper methods (or functions or subroutines or macros) are no sin if they come with a good name.

What's a good name?  One that ensures I don't have to look inside to know what it does. If I look inside after reading the name I should find pretty much what I expected.

It's only when you can't think of a good name that it makes sense not to abstract. When a good name is available abstraction should always be preferred.

Answer (score 5):

Normally I'd suggest exactly what you say you want to avoid: break into smaller functions.

The benefit is actually not for reusability but for unit testing. Each piece can independently be tested, which usually makes it easier to write tests. It also generally makes the tests more useful, because if there's a failure it's already more focused as to where it is.

If there are in fact a large number of common variables coming over, and they are related, I'd suggest another refactor then is to put them all into a struct or class and pass that to each function.

If they're not related, then something sounds strange about having to pass a large number to each of these sub-functions. Perhaps in this case you need to come at things with a different approach: think about how to make the smallest possible units of work (functions) that can be composed together.

There's no "one" correct approach here, it's very situational and subjective.

Comment: what's the benefit of "put a large number of common variables all into a struct or class"? my colleagues are against so..

Comment: @athos It depends -- if they are always being passed together, it sounds like they are probably representing a 'thing' of some sort, which is a pattern that naturally lends itself to being represented as an object. I would not put things together just for the sake of having a struct or class, though. Updated my answer with a bit of detail on this.